# Angular like button implementation using ngIf condition inside ngFor loop

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, ngfor

I'm working with YouTube style (like-dislike) buttons for my website. But i don't know how to do it. In my database i had two table posts(post_id, user_id, description), likes(like_id, user_id, post_id, like_status) columns values. I joined the two table and got the values by user_id, I just used posts with ngFor and implemented ngIf condition they are working fine if the user_id is in likes table .If the user_id not present in likes table i am unable to display the buttons, because i don't know the exact condition to the button in default status . Anyone please help me with this.

I have try following solutions but didn't work
 `*ngIf="( (postLikes.length != 0) && (post.user_id == like.user_id) && (post.post_id == like.post_id) && (like.like_status == 'like'))"`

`*ngIf="( (postLikes.length != 0) && (post.user_id == like.user_id) && (post.post_id == like.post_id) && (like.like_status == 'unlike'))"`

`*ngIf="( (postLikes.length == 0) && (post.user_id !== like.user_id) && (post.post_id !== like.post_id) && (like.like_status !== 'unlike'))"`

First two ngIf conditions are working fine but the final ngIf condition not working.

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;  ">
  <div class="row" style=" margin: 1px; background-color: #fff; border: 2px solid #ada5a5; border-radius: 4px; ">
    <!-- ngFor for posts -->
    <div class="container" *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index">
      <div class="row" style="border-top: 2px solid #ada5a5;">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-0" style=" height: auto; ">
          <h6> {{post.description}} </h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--ngFor for likes -->
      <div class="container" style="border: 0px solid #ada5a5; ">
        <div class="row">

          <!--like button-->
          <div class=" col-4">
            <div *ngFor="let like of postLikes; let j = index ">
              <div *ngIf="( (postLikes.length != 0) && (post.user_id == like.user_id) && (post.post_id == like.post_id) && (like.like_status == 'like'))">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)=likeSubmit(post.user_id,post.post_id)>Like</button><p>liked</p>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="( (postLikes.length != 0) && (post.user_id == like.user_id) && (post.post_id == like.post_id) && (like.like_status == 'unlike'))">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)=likeSubmit(post.user_id,post.post_id)>Like</button><p>Disliked</p>
              </div>

              <div
                *ngIf="( (postLikes.length == 0) && (post.user_id != like.user_id) && (post.post_id != like.post_id) && (like.like_status != 'unlike'))">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)=likeSubmit(post.user_id,post.post_id)>Like</button><p>Default</p>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- dislike button -->
          <div class=" col-6">
            <div class="" *ngFor="let like of postLikes">

              <div *ngIf="((post.user_id==like.user_id) && (post.post_id==like.post_id) && (like.like_status=='like'))">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)=likeSubmit(post.user_id,post.post_id)>Dislike</button>
              </div>
              <div
                *ngIf="((post.user_id==like.user_id) && (post.post_id==like.post_id) && (like.like_status=='unlike'))">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)=likeSubmit(post.user_id,post.post_id)>Disliked</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!--Like button ends-->     
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<TypeScript>

export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'my-app';
  name = 'Angular';

  posts: any[] =
    [{"post_id":4,"user_id":2,"description":" Hi How are you ","created_date":"2019-01-28T12:30:49.000Z"},{"post_id":5,"user_id":2,"description":" Working a Fine ","created_date":"2019-01-28T12:31:20.000Z"},{"post_id":6,"user_id":2,"description":" Hi How are you ......","created_date":"2019-01-28T12:32:15.000Z"},{"post_id":7,"user_id":2,"description":" 4th test post","created_date":"2019-01-29T07:10:37.000Z"},{"post_id":9,"user_id":2,"description":" 5th test post","created_date":"2019-01-31T11:17:31.000Z"},{"post_id":10,"user_id":2,"description":" 6th test post","created_date":"2019-01-31T12:03:54.000Z"},{"post_id":11,"user_id":2,"description":" 7th post post","created_date":"2019-02-08T05:50:02.000Z"},{"post_id":12,"user_id":2,"description":" 8th test post ","created_date":"2019-02-08T06:08:01.000Z"}];

  postLikes:any[] =[{"post_id":4,"user_id":2,"like_status":"unlike","like_id":10},{"post_id":5,"user_id":2,"like_status":"like","like_id":9},{"post_id":6,"user_id":2,"like_status":"like","like_id":8},{"post_id":7,"user_id":2,"like_status":"like","like_id":7},{"post_id":9,"user_id":2,"like_status":"like","like_id":11}]

  post_id: any;
  // likes: Like[];
  like_id: number | null ;
  like_status: string;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder){


  }

  ngOnInit() {   }

  // Get user details from DB
  getPosts(user_id) {
    this.userService.getPosts(user_id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.posts = data;
    },
      error => {
        return console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

// join postlikes
  getPostLikes(user_id) {
    // debugger
    this.userService.get_PostLikes(user_id).subscribe((results) => {
      this.postLikes = results;
     // console.log(results, 'results', this.postLikes, 'likes');
    },
      error => {
        return console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

I want ngIf condition to show the default button when the user_id is not in the likes table. My stackBlitz link 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wddupe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, I just can't add a comment, so...
First of all 'postLikes === 0' returns always *False* because 'postLikes' is an array, but '0' is type of number.
If you want to check if there are any values in array, then you can check it's length
f.e. if(postLikes.length === 0) or cleaner way **if(postLikes.length)**
Also read about what is the difference between '=' '==' '===' and fix your your other ngIf statements.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

As I understand you are getting all post_id-s that specific user has liked or unliked, so loop through postLikes array and if there is not that specific post_id then display your default like and dislike buttons.

Also I would suggest to refactor whole logic.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion